# How to update or refresh table links in MS Access using Python?

Tags: python, vba, ms-access

I can't seem to find a solution. I some vba code that I'm translating to python. One of the steps is to update some MS Access linked tables and I can't seem to replicate these steps.

Vba code:

```
FileCopy db, flenm
        
        appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase (flenm)
        
        Set myDb = appAccess.CurrentDb
        
'fles is an array made earlier w/ the new db names

        For Each tbl In myDb.TableDefs
            If InStr(1, tbl.Connect, "db_prefix ") <> 0 Then
                tbl.Connect = Replace(tbl.Connect, Basefolder & "my_db1.accdb", fles(0).Path)
                tbl.Connect = Replace(tbl.Connect, Basefolder & "my_db2.accdb", fles(1).Path)
                tbl.Connect = Replace(tbl.Connect, Basefolder & "my_db3.accdb", fles(2).Path)
                tbl.Connect = Replace(tbl.Connect, Basefolder & "my_db4.accdb", fles(3).Path)
                tbl.Connect = Replace(Replace(tbl.Connect, "_Template", "_" & flename), "\\server\path\to\folder", DestFolder)
                tbl.RefreshLink
            End If
        Next tbl
    appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
    myDb.Close
    Set myDb = Nothing
```

In Python I have the new dbs and the filepaths, what I'm struggling to do is mimic that tbl.RefreshLink that's in the vb6 code.

Python code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch


objAccess = Dispatch("Access.Application")
objAccess.Visible = False
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(db_path)
objDB = objAccess.CurrentDb()
for tbl in ObjDB.TableDefs:
     tbl.RefreshLink
objAccess.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: You could try `tbl.RefreshLink()`

Comment: "can't seem to replicate" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?